# Element UI autocomplete no results

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, element-ui

I use in my project [element UI autocomplete component](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/input#autocomplete-attributes).

When the input raises no result, I want to show a *no results* message.
In other projects I had it as an option in the suggest box (which is NOT selectable):

[image]

However, with element-ui autocomplete, after the searching icon disappears, the drop-down disappears as well:

[image]

With this component I do not manage to do so. Any idea?

My code looks like this:

**Template:**

```
<el-form ref="addressForm" :inline="true" :model="formData">
    <el-form-item prop="city">
        <el-autocomplete
                class="inline-input"
                v-model="formData.cityInput"
                :fetch-suggestions="getCities"
                placeholder="City"
                :trigger-on-focus="false"
                :clearable="true"
                @select="handleSelectCity"
                @clear="clearCity"
                size="small"
        ></el-autocomplete>
    </el-form-item>
        :
        :
    <el-form-item>
        <el-button type="primary" @click="onSubmit" size="small">
            Search
        </el-button>
    </el-form-item>
</el-form>
```

**Script:**

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            formData: {
                cityInput: "",
                city: "",
                :
                :
            },
        }
    },

    methods: {
        getCities(query, callback) {
            this.clearCity();

            // Ajax call to obtain results for autocomplete
            axios.get(
                "/cities", {
                    query: query
                })
                .then(
                    response => {
                        callback(response.data);
                    }
                );

        },

        handleSelectCity(item) {
            this.formData.city = item.value;
        },

        clearCity() {
            this.formData.city = "";
        },

        :
        :
        :
    }
};
```

**PHP code: (Laravel)**

```
public function getCities($query)
{
    $res = DB::connection('mainDb')
        ->table('offices')
        ->where('city', 'like', $query . '%')
        ->select('city AS value')
        ->distinct()
        ->get();

    return $res;
}
```

Comment: please share some code

Comment: maybe you can push 1 item with key & label, (no result), and if that was select you can check by key was selected, if key is from no result item, you can clear the input, what it make sense?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim, done.

Comment: @Ata, no, the idea is that user will NOT be able to select the "no results" option.

Comment: please share the code of ajax call

Comment: what's the exact issu, it seems work

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim, the problem is that it doesn't work. Just added an image to the question to make it clear.

Comment: there's no built in functionality like that, but you could do something like https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/ZEGvGNm

Comment: Thanks @BoussadjraBrahim, I have implemented already this functionality, I am looking for something more similar to what I put on the beginning of my question.

Comment: what about this https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/ZEGvGNm?editors=0000

Comment: Interesting... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this behaviour with `v-select`. There is a [filtering option](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/select#option-filtering) so you can either select option or type it down with autocomplete.

There are two attributes to control "no-result" case: `no-match-text` when filtering gave no result and `no-data-text` when there is no options in select.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, looks like these attributes do not exist for [autocomplete](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/input#autocomplete) component.

Comment: I was looking again and actually [these two attributes exist](https://element.eleme.io/2.8/#/en-US/component/select#select-attributes), even more - there is an  [`empty` slot](https://element.eleme.io/2.8/#/en-US/component/select#select-attributes) - but neither of them work for me :-(

Answer (score -3):

I tried el-select and it works good with "no matched data".But its remote-method  function isn't smart enough without callback parameter if you want to pass a function to it from outside component.
So,I have to try codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/ZEGvGNm, use the blur method to clear no matched data, and it works like the el-select.